# CSS центрирование transform: translate(-50%, -50%)

Tags: css

В CSS есть интересное преобраазование: `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`. Позволяет расположить элемент точно по центру экрана, если в результате применения центрирования типа text-align:center он оказался немного смещен.

Как работает такое преобразование? Если ему передать аргументы типа (1,  2), элемент будет смещен на такое число пикселей. А что означают проценты? От чего они отсчитываются?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аргументы  - это дельта по оси X и Y соответсвенно. 50% - это 50% размера центрируемого элемента. При размещении position: absolute; left: center; top: center; по центру размещается левая верхняя точка элемента. Поэтому его приходится сдвигать на половину размера.